# Do we have to create induvidual ViewModelLocators for each ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

Do we have to create induvidual ViewModelLocator for Different ViewModel or Only One ViewModelLocator for all ViewModels. Because When I try to use only one ViewModelLocator by making properties for all the ViewModels - It gives Error - Type Not Found in Cache. so m not able to use that viewmodel unless I set that viewModel as default.  Can anyone please help me identify where I am going wrong??

Comment: To help you we need to see at least the code for the view model locator. From what you write, though, I'd assume that you use some sort of IoC container and that the type you are looking for is not in this container ... but this is just a very wild guess!

Answer (score 3):

You only need one ViewModelLocator and need a setup similar to this:

You should have a ViewModelLocator.cs.

Have it initialized in your App.xaml:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Also your Views should be calling your ViewModelLocator at the root DataContext of each page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage DataContext="{Binding MenuViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" .../>
```

Comment: I found the solution -> Every time I use mvvmlocator snippet it generates new static constructor which I used to delete and finally got to above error because I don't register my ViewModel's property with SimpleIoc. I did it in the Default Constructor and the problem is Solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found better solution and work around of MVVM-Light ViewModelLocator is to use MEF Export.
Below is a good link by Johnpapa... Clean and Easy Solution.
http://johnpapa.net/simple-viewmodel-locator-for-mvvm-the-patients-have-left-the-asylum

Answer (score 0):

I caused this error in a Windows 8 store app when I used MVVM Toolkit just like you and had in my viewmodel's constructor the SimpleIoc container resolving types. This caused the design-time experience to show the error you describe.

I resolved it by checking if I was in design-time and not executing the code if I was